# Vague error when importing CSV file for Google AutoML Vision

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automl

When adding an image list to a dataset, I receive the following error:

> "Incorrect padding. The transaction could not be committed. Please try
>   again."

The image list contains 410k items and takes 15+ minutes to import, so just trying again doesn't seem the right course of action.

What does "Incorrect padding" mean and what can I do about it?

Comment: I was able to successfully add all of the images to the dataset by importing them piecemeal. Instead of a single monolithic CSV file, I broke it down into multiple smaller CSV files, each one corresponding to one of the labels.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your CSV has invalid format. What you can try is loading the CSV into a spreadsheet and making sure all paths start with gs:// prefix